C++ Base Class taking Type Parameter from Child Class
I would like to have a base class Collection that defines the following interfaces. The base class itself should implement none of this data but instead all of them should be provided by the child classes.

A type Member

A static function Member first_object()

A static function Member last_object()

A static function std::vector<Member> all_objects()


My issue is that I don't know how to have a base class with a type that is provided by a child class, i.e. the issue is with the Member type.
I was able to come up with the following implementation (full code at the bottom of the post):
template <typename Member>
struct CollectionBase {
    static Member first_object();
    static Member last_object();
    static std::vector<Member> all_objects();
};

struct CollectionA : CollectionBase<int> {
public:
    using Member = int;
private:
    static std::vector<Member> const objects;
public:
    static Member first_object() {
        return objects.front();
    }
    static Member last_object() {
        return objects.back();
    }
    static std::vector<Member> all_objects() {
        return objects;
    }
};

std::vector<CollectionA::Member> const CollectionA::objects = {1, 2, 3};

struct CollectionB : CollectionBase<std::string> {
public:
    using Member = std::string;
private:
    static std::vector<Member> const objects;
public:
    static Member first_object() {
        return objects.front();
    }
    static Member last_object() {
        return objects.back();
    }
    static std::vector<Member> all_objects() {
        return objects;
    }
};

std::vector<CollectionB::Member> const CollectionB::objects = {"One", "Two", "Three"};

template <typename Collection>
void do_stuff() {
    typename Collection::Member first_object = Collection::first_object();
    typename Collection::Member last_object = Collection::last_object();
    std::vector<typename Collection::Member> all_objects = Collection::all_objects();
    std::cout
        << "First object: " << first_object << std::endl
        << "Last object: " << last_object << std::endl
        << "All objects: " << all_objects << std::endl
    ;
}

int main() {
    do_stuff<CollectionA>();
    do_stuff<CollectionB>();
}

Output:
First object: 1
Last object: 3
All objects: { 1, 2, 3 }
First object: One
Last object: Three
All objects: { One, Two, Three }

This behavior is exactly what I want. However, I am unhappy with having to manually pass around the Member type parameter all the time. In fact, in my actual application, I have two types there, and this would become cumbersome.
I would prefer it if my code looked somewhat similar to the following code:
struct CollectionBase {
    static typename Member;
    static Member first_object();
    static Member last_object();
    static std::vector<Member> all_objects();
};

struct CollectionA : CollectionBase {
public:
    using Member = int;
private:
    static std::vector<Member> const objects;
public:
    static Member first_object() {
        return objects.front();
    }
    static Member last_object() {
        return objects.back();
    }
    static std::vector<Member> all_objects() {
        return objects;
    }
};

std::vector<CollectionA::Member> const CollectionA::objects = {1, 2, 3};

struct CollectionB : CollectionBase {
public:
    using Member = std::string;
private:
    static std::vector<Member> const objects;
public:
    static Member first_object() {
        return objects.front();
    }
    static Member last_object() {
        return objects.back();
    }
    static std::vector<Member> all_objects() {
        return objects;
    }
};

std::vector<CollectionB::Member> const CollectionB::objects = {"One", "Two", "Three"};

template <typename Collection>
void do_stuff() {
    typename Collection::Member first_object = Collection::first_object();
    typename Collection::Member last_object = Collection::last_object();
    std::vector<typename Collection::Member> all_objects = Collection::all_objects();
    std::cout
        << "First object: " << first_object << std::endl
        << "Last object: " << last_object << std::endl
        << "All objects: " << all_objects << std::endl
    ;
}

int main() {
    do_stuff<CollectionA>();
    do_stuff<CollectionB>();
}

For emphasis, here is the git diff:
@@ -1,11 +1,11 @@
-template <typename Member>
 struct CollectionBase {
+       static typename Member;
        static Member first_object();
        static Member last_object();
        static std::vector<Member> all_objects();
 };

-struct CollectionA : CollectionBase<int> {
+struct CollectionA : CollectionBase {
 public:
        using Member = int;
 private:
@@ -24,7 +24,7 @@ public:

 std::vector<CollectionA::Member> const CollectionA::objects = {1, 2, 3};

-struct CollectionB : CollectionBase<std::string> {
+struct CollectionB : CollectionBase {
 public:
        using Member = std::string;
 private:

Is it possible to do this?

Full working example (GodBolt Link):
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::vector<T> const& v)
{
    os << "{ ";
    bool first = true;
    for (T const& t : v) {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            os << ", ";
        os << t;
    }
    os << " }";
    return os;
}

template <typename Member>
struct CollectionBase {
    static Member first_object();
    static Member last_object();
    static std::vector<Member> all_objects();
};

struct CollectionA : CollectionBase<int> {
public:
    using Member = int;
private:
    static std::vector<Member> const objects;
public:
    static Member first_object() {
        return objects.front();
    }
    static Member last_object() {
        return objects.back();
    }
    static std::vector<Member> all_objects() {
        return objects;
    }
};

std::vector<CollectionA::Member> const CollectionA::objects = {1, 2, 3};

struct CollectionB : CollectionBase<std::string> {
public:
    using Member = std::string;
private:
    static std::vector<Member> const objects;
public:
    static Member first_object() {
        return objects.front();
    }
    static Member last_object() {
        return objects.back();
    }
    static std::vector<Member> all_objects() {
        return objects;
    }
};

std::vector<CollectionB::Member> const CollectionB::objects = {"One", "Two", "Three"};

template <typename Collection>
void do_stuff() {
    typename Collection::Member first_object = Collection::first_object();
    typename Collection::Member last_object = Collection::last_object();
    std::vector<typename Collection::Member> all_objects = Collection::all_objects();
    std::cout
        << "First object: " << first_object << std::endl
        << "Last object: " << last_object << std::endl
        << "All objects: " << all_objects << std::endl
    ;
}

int main() {
    do_stuff<CollectionA>();
    do_stuff<CollectionB>();
}

Output:
First object: 1
Last object: 3
All objects: { 1, 2, 3 }
First object: One
Last object: Three
All objects: { One, Two, Three }


What is the purpose of the CollectionBase base class?

@Mestkon I imagined it to specify a kind of interface. But now that you mention it, I suppose that it is not actually necessary... Perhaps this is already the answer to my question

You might then write concept instead, and static_assert(is_collection_of<CollectionA, int>);

@Jarod42 Could you expand this into an answer? I'm not really familiar with concepts.

Demo using concept. but using regular template might be enough and simpler.

The CollectionBase class is simply unnecessary. The following code would work just as well (GodBolt Link):
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::vector<T> const& v)
{
    os << "{ ";
    bool first = true;
    for (T const& t : v) {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            os << ", ";
        os << t;
    }
    os << " }";
    return os;
}

struct CollectionA {
public:
    using Member = int;
private:
    static std::vector<Member> const objects;
public:
    static Member first_object() {
        return objects.front();
    }
    static Member last_object() {
        return objects.back();
    }
    static std::vector<Member> all_objects() {
        return objects;
    }
};

std::vector<CollectionA::Member> const CollectionA::objects = {1, 2, 3};

struct CollectionB {
public:
    using Member = std::string;
private:
    static std::vector<Member> const objects;
public:
    static Member first_object() {
        return objects.front();
    }
    static Member last_object() {
        return objects.back();
    }
    static std::vector<Member> all_objects() {
        return objects;
    }
};

std::vector<CollectionB::Member> const CollectionB::objects = {"One", "Two", "Three"};

template <typename Collection>
void do_stuff() {
    typename Collection::Member first_object = Collection::first_object();
    typename Collection::Member last_object = Collection::last_object();
    std::vector<typename Collection::Member> all_objects = Collection::all_objects();
    std::cout
        << "First object: " << first_object << std::endl
        << "Last object: " << last_object << std::endl
        << "All objects: " << all_objects << std::endl
    ;
}

int main() {
    do_stuff<CollectionA>();
    do_stuff<CollectionB>();
}

